# Resize blocks in a Azure storage block blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Say I had a blob with N blocks of varying size, and where the length of a set of continuous block were short enough that two or more consecutive blocks could be actually be merged into 1 block (within the max per block length restrictions of the service)

This could be achieved by downloading just the set of continuous blocks, combining them, uploading that block, and committing the new block list.

Rather than pull the blocks back to my own machine, it would be nice to take advantage of the [Put Block From Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-from-url?tabs=azure-ad) operation and specify a URL to the Azure Blob service.

But is it possible to use this option to only pull a specific set of blocks ?

Answer (score 0):

> But is it possible to use this option to only pull a specific set of
> blocks ?

I would say no.

While it is possible to get partial content of the source blob by specifying the range using `x-ms-source-range` header, what you are trying to do is combine data from two or more blocks and save that as a single block in blob which is not possible with `Put Block From Url` operation.

You will need to download the blocks locally, merge them and then reupload those blocks and commit a new block list.